# How can I deactivate or make private my Wordpress.com as well as Wordpress.org blogs?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress.com

All I found via Google was outdated advice. In neither the Wordpress.com nor Wordpress.org (i.e. installation on own domain) can I find any option in the "security" or privacy settings aside from the one setting of "Search Engine Visibility", i.e. "Discourage search engines from indexing this site".

Basically I want to *either* temporarily deactivate my blog (i.e. make it completely inaccessible) *or* make its - previously public - content private. Is that possible as of April 2013 or in Wordpress 3.6? (Which I have installed right now.)

I hope this question is within the scope of the Wordpress questions allowed here.

Comment: WordPress.com questions are on-topic here. WordPress.org questions are better off at [wordpress.se].

Answer (score 1):

For a WordPress.com blog:

Under `Settings - Reading` (`http://<blog>.wordpress.com/wp-admin/options-reading.php`)

In the "Site Visibility" section

Tick the radio button for "I would like my site to be private, visible only to users I choose"

[image: snippet from WordPress.com settings panel]

Answer (score 0):

A web-based way that works for both .com and .org blogs, from your blog Dashboard menu:

- Under `Posts`, `All Posts`, click on either `All` or `Published` above the list of posts (either one should do it).
- Below this, change the `Bulk Actions` drop-down menu to `Edit`.
- Tick the check-box beside `Title`. This should select everything *on that page* on the list of posts.
- Beside the `Edit` drop-down menu, click the `Apply` button.
- In the menu that slides down, change the `Status` drop-down menu to `Private`, then click `Apply`.

**Note:** You'll have to do these steps this for each page of posts in the list.